# Finding Culprit Blocking Sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Whenever in our system there is a block (everything stopped). I see the below query is the culprit,

```
  (@P1 numeric(10))SELECT "Col1128","Tbl1029"."A_NAME" "Col1124" FROM "DbName"."Schema"."MyTable1" 
"Tbl1029" RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT "Tbl1027"."MyColumn1" "Col1126","Tbl1027"."MyColumn2" 
"Col1127","Tbl1027"."MyColumn4" "Col1128","Tbl1027"."MyColumn5" "Col1130","Tbl1027"."MyColumn6" 
"Col1129","Tbl1027"."MyColumn5" "Col1131" FROM "DbName"."Schame"."MyTable2" "Tbl1027" WHERE 
"Tbl1027"."MyColumn1"=@P1) Qry1132 ON CONVERT(numeric(2,0),"Tbl1029"."MyColumn3",0)="Col1126"
```

We have 2 separate DB servers with completely different databases. The above is running in DB server 2 but request is coming DB server 1 (client host name). We have 100 of applications connecting to DB servers. Also, we have link server among DB servers.

Now, I know that the query came form DB server 1 with ProgramName `Microsoft SQL Server`. Now I am confused whether the program `Microsoft SQL Server` is indicating the link server query or application query using ORM.

I am searching in all applications but not finding anything yet. Form the DBA perspective what else I can do to get the real issue

Comment: Did you try running sp_whoisactive or sp_blitzwho and see?

Comment: I'd capture the behavior using Extended Events. Get the batch, statement, proc (probably not a proc) information. That'll tell you who is calling, resources used, all of it. You can also capture the blocking process itself the same way to get a better determination on the blocking chain. All that should tell you what you need.

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin I use sp_whoisactive with find_block_leaders. When I kill this everything start working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Now, I know that the query came form DB server 1 with ProgramName Microsoft SQL Server. Now I am confused whether the program Microsoft SQL Server is indicating the link server query or application query using ORM.
```

The host name "DB server 1" along with the "Microsoft SQL Server" program name indicates a linked server query, not a query executed directly from the application.

> From the DBA perspective what else I can do to get the real issue?

As @Learning_DBAdmin suggested in comments, examine the active queries running on DB server 1 during the blocking episode. One or more should show the query with the linked server along with the originating application host and program name.

The real issue is likely the need for query/index tuning to optimize the remote query. You may need indexes on the join/where clause columns. The explict conversion on `Tbl1029.MyColumn3` will preclude using an index on the column efficiently (if one exists). The resultant full scans can lead to blocking.